# What is the order of joints in jointsLocalTransforms / jointsModelTransforms of ARBodyAnchor in ARKit3?

Tags: swift, arkit, arbodyanchor

I'm working on capturing 3D motion using ARKit3 in which I get transforms of all the Joints by using `jointsModelTransforms` or `jointsLocalTransforms` in `session:didUpdate:` delegate method of `ARSessionDelegate` like below

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
  for anchor in anchors {
    guard let bodyAnchor = anchor as? ARBodyAnchor else { continue }
    let bodyTransforms: [simd_float4x4] = bodyAnchor.skeleton.jointModelTransforms
    // TODO
  }
}
```

First index of `bodyTransforms` array is the `root` joint. 
Would like to know the order of joints in which the array is represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arskeletondefinition) is a documentation about the `ARSkeletonDefinition`, the class containing the hierarchy of joints and their names.

In your case, names and order of the joints can be easily obtained via calling `bodyAnchor.skeleton.definition.jointNames`.